# Postgresql error No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: postgresql

```
declare r double precision; b double precision; c double precision;
begin

  r:=9.2;
  b:=2.3;
  c:=r/b;

  select log(2.7, c);
  ...
```

But I get an error for this code:

> ERROR: function log(numeric, double precision) does not exist
>   LINE 1: select log(2.7, c)
>
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
>
> QUERY:  select log(2.7, c)
>   CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 11 at SQL statement
>   SQL state: 42883

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE) the `log()` function with two arguments requires `numeric` not `double precision`

```
do
$$
declare
  r numeric; 
  b numeric; 
  c numeric;
  result numeric;
begin

  r:=9.2;
  b:=2.3;
  c:=r/b;

  result := log(2.7, c);
  raise notice 'Result %', result;
end;
$$
```

Answer (score 1):

The `log` function in PostgreSQL with two arguments requires `NUMERIC` parameters:

```
 \df log 
                          List of functions
   Schema   | Name | Result data type | Argument data types |  Type  
------------+------+------------------+---------------------+--------
 pg_catalog | log  | double precision | double precision    | normal
 pg_catalog | log  | numeric          | numeric             | normal
 pg_catalog | log  | numeric          | numeric, numeric    | normal
```

So you should cast your second argument or use a numeric variable instead:

```
SELECT LOG(2.7, c::NUMERIC);
```